# Transformation linearity and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider $E$ as a linear subspace in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with dimension $k$ and F as a linear subspace in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with dimension $n-k$, such that $E\cap F=\{0\}$

The transformation $p:\mathbb{R^n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R^n}$ defined as followes:

for every $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ consider the subspace $F^\prime$ that goes throgh $x$ and parallel to $F$ with the same dimension as $F$, since $E\cap F$ is a point, so $E\cap F^\prime$ is a point too, name this point $p(x)$

First I want to prove that this transformation is linear, so I should prove that for every $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ we have:

1. $p(x+x^\prime)=p(x)+p(x^\prime)$
2. $p(cx)=cp(x)$

I know that $F^\prime$ is $F$ transferred by $x$, so these 2 conditions  seems true but I don't know how to express my prove mathematically.

Then I want to find a base for $\mathbb{R^n}$ like $\mathfrak{B}$ such that:

$M^{\mathfrak{B}}_{\mathfrak{B}^\prime}(p)=\begin{bmatrix}
I_k & O\\O&O
\end{bmatrix}$

I found this for $\mathfrak{B}$:

$\mathfrak{B}={\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_k,f_{k+1},\dots,f_{n}\}}$

where $e_j$ are elements of $E$ and $f_j$ are elements of $F$

Is this correct?

And how do I can find eigenvalues and characteristic polynomial of $p$?

Comment: $p$ is indeed linear and is called the projection onto $E$ parallel to $F$. The eigenvalues of $p$ are zero and $1$ because $p(e) = e$ for $e\in E$ and $p(f) = 0$ for $f\in F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work with the basis you suggested: Let $e_1,\ldots, e_k$ and $f_{k+1},\ldots, f_n$ be bases for $E$ and $F$ respectively. Then $\mathfrak B = \{e_1,\ldots, e_k, f_{k+1},\ldots, f_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^n$ (since $E$ and $F$ have trivial intersection). Let $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ in this basis, and let's compute $p(x)$.

**Edit:** Remember that $p(x) \in E\cap F^\prime$. Because of the way we chose the basis, a vector in $E$ is of the form $(a_1,\ldots,a_k,0,\ldots,0)$ for some $a_i\in\mathbb R$. Similarly, a vector in $F$ is of the form $(0,\ldots,0,b_{k+1},\ldots,b_n)$ for some $b_i\in\mathbb R$, which means that a vector in $F' = x+F$ is of the form $x+(0,\ldots,0,b_{k+1},\ldots,b_n)$. Since $p(x)$ is both a vector in $E$ and in $F'$, we can now write $p(x)$ in two ways:

$$
p(x) = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_k \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad {\rm and} \qquad
p(x) = x + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ b_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ b_n 
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_k \\ x_{k+1}+b_{k+1} \\ \vdots \\ x_n+b_n 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(**Edit end**)

We see that this forces $a_i=x_i$ for all $1 \le i \le k$, so that we have the unique solution:

$$
p(x) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_k \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

We see that $p$ is the linear transformation given by the matrix you wrote. The characteristic polynomial is:

$$
{\rm det}(xI-M) = (x-1)^kx^{n-k}
$$

with eigenvalues 0 and 1 (assuming $0<k<n$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, But I didn't understand the part which you wrote $p(x)$ in two ways. Would you mind explaining it a little more?

Comment: Of course, I can see I went a bit fast there. See if my edit clarifies things for you.